# Temporarily hiding/removing ComboBox items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ComboBox` that displays some objects by using this *simplified* template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10,0,2,0" 
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="11" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ComboBox` has predefined items (they extend from `FrameworkElement`), but depending on other parameters, I need to hide some of these items.

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,3,5,3" Height="38" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}">
    <i:GenericItem x:Name="SomethingItem" Title="Something" Description="Abc" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Something}"/>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="ElseItem" Title="Else" Description="Def" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Else}"/>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="GoesItem" Title="Goes" Description="Ghj" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Goes}"/>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="HereItem" Title="Here" Description="Ijk" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Here}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I'm wondering if there's a simple way, like setting `IsEnabled`, to hide these items?

Without having to add/remove the items from the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle` that sets the `Visibility` property of the `ComboBoxItem` container to `Collapsed` based on some property value of a `GenericItem`, e.g.:

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,3,5,3" Height="38" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="SomethingItem" Title="Something" Description="Abc" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Something}"/>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="ElseItem" Title="Else" Description="Def" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Else}"/>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="GoesItem" Title="Goes" Description="Ghj" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Goes}"/>

    <i:GenericItem x:Name="HereItem" Title="Here" Description="Ijk" Value="{x:Static u:MyEnum.Here}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The above sample markup should hide any item that gets disabled.